# How to Group and or Select in Linq based on a running total

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a requirement where I need to group and select transactions where the running amounts exceed a threshold of 10. Once they exceed the threshold, the running count will be reset.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do...

Below are some transactions:

```
Id | Amount
1  | 5.50
2  | 4.10
3  | 1.20
4  | 1.05
5  | 3.25
6  | 1.25
7  | 5.15
8  | 8.15
9  | 5.15
```

The result I would like to achieve is:

Group 1:

```
Id | Amount
1  | 5.50
2  | 4.10    
3  | 1.20
```

Group 2:

```
4  | 1.05
5  | 3.25    
6  | 1.25   
7  | 5.15
```

Group 3:

```
8  | 8.15
9  | 5.15
```

I've come up with a solution which uses a for loop and yield. You can see it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcSJO4 and also further below.

I just wondered if there was a more elegant solution and if there is a clever and more readable way that can be achieved using Linq.

My solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Transaction{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public decimal Amount { get; set;}        
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var transactions = new Transaction [] { 
            new Transaction {Id = 1, Amount = 5.50m},
            new Transaction {Id = 2, Amount = 4.10m},
            new Transaction {Id = 3, Amount = 1.20m},
            new Transaction {Id = 4, Amount = 1.05m},
            new Transaction {Id = 5, Amount = 3.25m},
            new Transaction {Id = 6, Amount = 1.25m},
            new Transaction {Id = 7, Amount = 5.15m},
            new Transaction {Id = 8, Amount = 8.15m},
            new Transaction {Id = 9, Amount = 5.15m},
        };

        var grouped = ApplyGrouping(transactions);

        foreach(var g in grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + g.Item1);

            foreach(var t in g.Item2){
                Console.WriteLine(" " +t.Amount);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------");
        }

    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<decimal, IEnumerable<Transaction>>> ApplyGrouping(IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions){

        decimal runningTotal = 0m;
        decimal threshold = 10m;

        var grouped = new List<Transaction>();

        foreach(var t in transactions){

            grouped.Add(t);
            runningTotal += t.Amount;

            if (runningTotal <= threshold) continue;

            yield return new Tuple<decimal, IEnumerable<Transaction>>(runningTotal, grouped);

            grouped.Clear();
            runningTotal = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are going to find a solution that is completely satisfying.  There are no built in Linq operators (or combination of operators) that are going to do this in a way that is aesthetically pleasing.  Your approach - refactoring the complexity into an extension method - is the best approach.  There is nothing wrong with that.  That is all Linq is, anyway; just an abstraction that hides the messy bits.  However, if you find yourself using this pattern often I would say that you could refactor your code into something a little more general.  What you have now is only going to work in this one very specific situation.  If you do something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupUntil<TSource, TAccumulation, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TAccumulation> seedFactory,
        Func<TAccumulation, TSource, TAccumulation> accumulator,
        Func<TAccumulation, bool> predicate,
        Func<TAccumulation, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> selector)
    {
        TAccumulation accumulation = seedFactory();
        List<TSource> result = new List<TSource>();
        using(IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                result.Add(enumerator.Current);
                accumulation = accumulator(accumulation, enumerator.Current);
                if(predicate(accumulation))
                {
                    yield return selector(accumulation, result);
                    accumulation = seedFactory();
                    result = new List<TSource>();
                }
            }

            if(result.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return selector(accumulation, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for your case, you could call it like this:

```
var grouped = 
    transactions
    .GroupUntil(
        () => 0.0m,
        (accumulation, transaction) => accumulation + transaction.Amount,
        (accumulation) => accumulation > 10.0m,
        (accumulation, group) => new { Total = accumulation, Transactions = group})
```

But it is generic enough that it could be used elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I would stick to your solution. Even if you can hack it around using LINQ it most likely won't be readable.

The only thing you should change is the way to use the same `List<T>` over and over again and clear it after returning - because `List<T>` is a reference type you're clearing already returned items too.

Create new `List<T>` instad of calling `Clear` on the previous one.

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<decimal, IEnumerable<Transaction>>> ApplyGrouping(IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions){

    decimal runningTotal = 0m;
    decimal threshold = 10m;

    var grouped = new List<Transaction>();

    foreach(var t in transactions){
        grouped.Add(t);
        runningTotal += t.Amount;

        if (runningTotal <= threshold) continue;

        yield return new Tuple<decimal, IEnumerable<Transaction>>(runningTotal, grouped);

        grouped = new List<Transaction>();
        runningTotal = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...but he's looking for LINQ

Answer (score -1):

Here's a LINQ way to do it

```
    var runningTotal = 0.0m;

    List<List<Transaction>> list = new List<List<Transaction>>();
    List<Transaction> currentList = new List<Transaction>();

    transactions.Select(x => {
        runningTotal += x.Amount;
        currentList.Add(x);
        if (runningTotal >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group 1 Total {0}", runningTotal);
            runningTotal = 0;
            list.Add(currentList);
            currentList = new List<Transaction>();
        }
        return runningTotal;
        }).ToList();
```